# Server hanging when changing data types using postgresql and jpa

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jpa

I've been working on a Spring boot server using JPA/Hibernate as an ORM and PostgresQL on the backend. To deploy I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I had two columns that were a timestamp but I'd like to convert them to a string.

To do this, I connected to the database, changed the two columns to varchar, changed the data type in the model in the code, and redeployed the application. When I do this, all server connections (either CrudRepository.save or CrudRepository.update) to the modified table hang, and then after a period of time (probably 5-10 minutes), the server starts responding to connections, but the data type is reverted to what it was before (timestamp).

code before:

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTimePerformed;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endTimePerformed;
```

code after:

```java
private String startTimeScheduled;
private String endTimeScheduled;
```

SQL used to alter the types:

```sql
ALTER TABLE appointment ALTER COLUMN start_time_scheduled TYPE varchar;
```

Expected results: When trying to insert a new record into the database with the server, the server correctly inserts the new datatype.

What is the correct way to migrate data with JPA and PostgresQL?

Comment: Try to do a commit after the alter table

Comment: @SimonMartinelli this worked, thank you so much! When do I need to commit in the future?

Comment: I add my comment as answer. Just a question How do you execute the alter?

Comment: I used SQL workbench to connect to the database, which was an AWS RDS db. I then executed the ALTER TABLE command and checked the types of the columns, which matched up.

Comment: Then you have been in your own transaction that's why you saw the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL commands are transactional in PostgreSQL.

So you have to add a commit after the alter statement if the the alter statement runs in a transaction. Otherwise you are blocking other transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with database migration tool like flyway or liquidbase for your production database migration stuff. So that it can easily maintain schema modification history.